# Populate Combobox from db - ValueMember issue

Tags: vb.net, combobox, valuemember

I cannot find a reason, why in my case a the DisplayMember gets populated correctly and ValueMember gets instead only a string (column name). It's same for different comboboxes, column names and tables.

```
            Using comm3 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT PID, RTRIM(Desc) as Desc FROM Conds WHERE Typ = 3", oConn)
                Dim rs As SqlDataReader = comm3.ExecuteReader
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
                dt.Load(rs)
                cbConditionPayment.ValueMember = "PID"
                cbConditionPayment.DisplayMember = "Desc"
                cbConditionPayment.DataSource = dt
            End Using 'comm3
```

So DisplayMember gets values like "Condition1, Condition2, Condition3,....", while
ValueMember gets values "PID, PID, PID, PID,...." instead of "1, 2, 3, 18, 22, ..."

Must be something stupid...

Regards,

Oak

Comment: Did you try to change the DisplayMember from DESC to Popis? By the way DESC should be in square brakets because is a reserved keyword

Comment: Sorry, this is not a problem, I just translated the query to English for better understanding. In the original case, there's Popis in both fields.

Comment: did you solved this problem ? and how ? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may have misunderstood what the `ValueMember` does.  How are you actually getting those "PID" values?  Are you getting them from the `ValueMember` property?  If so then that's exactly what you'd expect because that's what you assigned to it in the first place.

The `ValueMember` is the name of the column from which the `SelectedValue` gets its value.  When the user selects an item by its "Desc" value, the `SelectedValue` property will return the corresponding "PID" value.